# How to get environment variable in Cloud Run?

Tags: node.js, express, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-run

I have set some environment variables using Google Cloud Console as described in the documentation [here](https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/configuring/environment-variables#console).

However, I can't figure out how (or where to read about) accessing the environment variables in my node js container.

Comment: You can read an environment variable in your node js code using `process.env.<NAME>`.  Docs for it are [here](https://nodejs.org/api/process.html#process_process_env)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You mean how to do you read them in the node.js code?

process.env is the way to get them.

I.e. if you have an env var: "MyVariable" then you could call in your node.js:

`process.env.MyVariable` to retrieve the value.

Remember that in node, all variables are strings. So even if you have a boolean value set, or an int, it'll come through as a string, so be careful of that. If you set a 0, and just test it as a boolean, it'll always be true because it's actually the string "0" and not an actual 0.